# Implementing a timeline slider using silverlight or ajax?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, silverlight, timeline

I want to ask you for direction for creating a timeline slider similar to the one in [Plurk](http://www.plurk.com).

I want to arrange my events on a timeline and make the user slide through this time line to navigate the events.

I just want to know weather I can do it using silverlight or not ? or any other feature in the .NET platform.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an example somewhere other than Plurk? Somewhere you don't have to sign up!?

Comment: you don't have to sign up  .... check this public profile:
http://www.plurk.com/Mico_Soul_LeAd

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do one in Silverlight by styling the ListBox control.  You would modify the ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate in Expression Blend to do so - you would also need to create a ValueConverter to position the timeline items.  Although [this article](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=40) was written about WPF, you can now do all of the things in it with Silverlight.  The article gives a good idea of what you would do and how you would do it.